# ¿A qué se debe este funcionamiento en PHP cuando se usan valores de array dentro de comillas dobles y fuera de ellas?

Tags: php

Dado que mucha gente escribe código mezclando bloques HTML/PHP (lo cual debería estar prohibido... es lo más ilegible que he visto), siempre recomiendo escribir un solo bloque donde se concatena una sola variable rodeada por comillas dobles.

En el caso de los arrays, el código en esos casos se puede escribir así:

```
$html="Este es el valor de clave1: $mArray[clave1]";
$html.="... más cosas";
$html.=" y este es el valor de clave2: $mArray[clave2]";
echo $html;
```

En definitiva, yo puedo en una cadena rodeada por comillas dobles usar algo como `$mArray[clave]`, pero si lo hago directamente funciona, pero arroja un Notice.

#### Prueba que funciona limpiamente:

```
$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor");
echo "El valor es: $mArray[clave]";
```

**Salida:**

```
El valor es: valor
```

#### Prueba que funciona, pero arroja un Notice:

```
$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor");
echo "El valor es: ".$mArray[clave];
```

**Salida:**

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant clave - assumed 'clave' in ...
El valor es: valor
```

¿Sabe alguien a qué se debe este comportamiento en PHP? En el segundo caso muestra el dato, pero arroja un Notice. **¿No debería arrojar un Notice también en el primer caso, puesto que estoy usando `clave` sin más? ¿Por qué no arroja Notice?**

Comment: has probado a escribir `$mArray['clave']`? con comillas simples

Comment: @Juanant mi duda es sobre todo por qué en el primer caso lo reconoce sin emitir ningún Notice.

Comment: Aparte de estar de acuerdo en no mezclar bloques PHP y html ( cómo se hace en los frameworks actuales utilizando motores de plantilla tipo twig) si seguimos los estándares psr se solucionan muchos problemas, entre ellos este que comentas

Comment: Veo algunas respuestas con muchos votos positivos pero que básicamente no responden la pregunta (que es muy buena, por cierto).

Answer (score 12):

Partimos de que los **NOTICE** nos ayudan a identificar *variables no inicializadas o capturar errores en nombres de variables* de acuerdo con [la documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php)

Posterior identificamos que el mensaje que te aparece:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant clave - assumed 'clave' in ...
>   valor

Se debe a que tratas de imprimir así

```
$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor");
echo "El valor es: ".$mArray[clave];
```

Donde *clave* debería estar entre comillada para identificarse como una clave de tu array asociativo, pero al no ser así se trata de leer como una constante **el problema por el cual surge el `NOTICE` es que precisamente indica que dicha constante no esta inicializada en ningún lado**; recordemos que en PHP las constantes se declaran de este modo

```
define('IVA', 12.3);

echo IVA;
```

Características:

- No uso del signo de dólar `$`
- Se imprime la constante sin comillas

Dado lo anterior para PHP leer `echo $myArray[clave];` es como si trataras de imprimir el valor de una constante que no esta difinida como tal, pero que al hacer la lectura del código de manera secuencial si la encuentra como `key` dentro de la estructura de un array asociativo por eso de todos modos imprime su valor.

De lo anterior podemos sacar un ejemplo, cambia el valor de `clave` en echo y coloca una mayúscula así

```
<?php

$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor");
echo "El valor es: ".$mArray[Clave];
```

Lo anterior nos dará esto como resultado

> **Warning**:  Use of undefined constant Clave - assumed
>   'Clave' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   **[...][...]** on line **4**
>  
>  **Notice**: 
>   Undefined index: Clave in **[...][...]** on line **4**
>  El
>   valor es:

¿Por qué?

Como te mencionaba al hacer la lectura del código el interprete de PHP en tu caso encuentra una coincidencia pero no como constante si no como *key* por eso a pesar del aviso imprime el valor, en este último ejemplo ya no lo hará por que la constante no declarada no coincide con la *key* del array asociativo

Bajo el primer escenario con el uso de las comillas dobles, se imprime sin el `NOTICE` por que estas hacen que el contenido sea evaluado; es decir al hacer esto:

```
echo "El valor es: $mArray[clave]";
```

Se lee una variable que contiene un arreglo y su clave respectiva

Es decir si hacemos uso de `var_dump()`

```
var_dump("$mArray[clave]");
```

obtendremos un resultado como este

> string(5) "valor"

Donde se esta evaluando y obteniendo el valor de su clave

Mientras que si lo hacemos con comillas simples, así

```
var_dump('$mArray[clave]');
```

El resultado será este

> string(14) "$mArray[clave]"

Por que se lee como una string de forma literal

Ahora si hacemos lo siguiente

```
var_dump($mArray[clave]);
```

Obtendremos esto por salida

> NOTICE Use of undefined constant clave - assumed 'clave' on line
>   number 8 string(5) "valor"

Donde si encuentra el valor, pero tiene el problema que lo asume como una constante

- Mas información respecto al uso de [comillas dobles en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo de la constante más o menos lo entiendo, lo que más me extraña es que en el primer caso sí reconoce el valor sin emitir ningún Notice, ¿sabes por qué?

Comment: El uso de las comillas dobles hace que el intérprete de PHP evalúe el contenido de las variables y/o constantes, por lo que evaluará que es una variable que contiene un array asociativo del cual se trata de imprimir una key determinada

Answer (score 9):

En `PHP` previamente comprueba si `clave` se definió como una constante. Lamentablemente, en lugar de morir con un error grave en este punto, emite ese aviso y actúa como si una constante se hubiera definido con el mismo nombre y valor:

```
define('clave', 'clave');
```

Al hacer eso no saldrá dicho *Warning*.

**Código:**

```
define('clave', 'clave');  

$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor");
echo "El valor es: $mArray[clave]";

$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor");
echo "El valor es: ".$mArray[clave];
```

Fuente SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025500/8484418

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo de la constante más o menos lo entiendo, lo que más me extraña es que en el primer caso sí reconoce el valor sin emitir ningún Notice, ¿sabes por qué?

Answer (score 5):

**Por un lado** tenemos que al usar comillas dobles, `PHP` agrega la funcionalidad que se conoce como [`Análisis de strings (String parsing)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

> Cuando un `string` es especificado mediante comillas dobles o mediante heredoc, las variables que haya dentro de dicho string se analizarán.
>
> Existen dos tipos de sintaxis: una [simple](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) y otra [compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).
>
> La [sintaxis simple](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) es la más empleada y práctica. Proporciona una forma de embeber una variable, un valor de un array o una propiedad de un object dentro de un string con el mínimo esfuerzo.
>
> La [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) puede ser reconocida por las llaves que delimitan la expresión.

Usando la **sintaxis simple**, la regla para acceder a posiciones de arreglos es no usar comillas.

---

**Por otro lado**, tenemos la sintaxis para el [uso de constantes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.syntax.php).

> Estas son las diferencias entre constantes y variables:
>    - Las constantes no llevan el signo dólar ($), como prefijo.
>    - Antes de PHP 5.3, las constantes solo podían ser definidas usando la función define(), y no por simple asignación.
>    - Las constantes pueden ser definidas y accedidas desde cualquier sitio sin importar las reglas de acceso de variables.
>    - Las constantes no pueden ser redefinidas o eliminadas una vez se han definido; y
>    - Las constantes podrían evaluarse como valores escalares. A partir de PHP 5.6 es posible definir una constante de array con la palabra reservada const, y, a partir de PHP 7, las constantes de array también se pueden definir con define(). Se pueden utilizar arrays en expresiones escalares constantes (por ejemplo, const FOO = array(1,2,3)[0];), aunque el resultado final debe ser un valor de un tipo permitido.

El `notice` surge (como ya lo ha dicho [@MarioGuiber](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258328/16597)) por que la sintaxis `clave` determina que se debe interpretar como una constante y dado que no es definida, obtienes dicho mensaje.

Lectura recomendada: [¿Por qué es incorrecto `$foo[bar]`?](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: @A.Cedano Entiendo que esta es la respuesta que mas se acerca a la cuestion. No obstante entiendo que la duda es ¿por que la clave de un array sin comillas dentro de un string entre comillas dobles es interpretada como string y no como constante? La respuesta es que el Análisis de variables dentro de un string solo expande las variables pero no puede expandir constantes, por lo que `clave1` en `$html="Este es el valor de clave1: $mArray[clave1]"` es interpretado como string, si el indice existe es un valor se expande sin problema.

Answer (score 4):

Esto es un comportamiento curioso de PHP, pero que radica en que **las constantes no pueden ser directamente expandidas dentro de un string** entre comillas doble o heredoc, el manual nos dice:

[Análisis de variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

> Cuando un string es especificado mediante comillas dobles o mediante heredoc, las variables que haya dentro de dicho string se analizarán.

También podemos encontrar la siguiente nota en el mismo enlace, en Sintaxis compleja (llaves):

> Cualquier **variable escalar, elemento de array o propiedad de objeto** con una representación de tipo string puede ser incluido a través de esta sintaxis

Debemos tener en cuenta que **variable != constante**. Las variables y las constantes son cosas diferentes.

---

Pasemos a los ejemplo:

### ¿Qué está sucediendo?

```
<?php
define('clave', "valor constante");
$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor array");
echo "El valor es: $mArray[clave]";
//  El valor es: valor array
?>
```

> En este caso PHP asume que `clave` es un string al estar dentro de un string, no una contante, ya que las contantes no pueden ser expandidas dentro de un string.

```
<?php
$mArray=array("clave2"=>"valor");
echo "El valor es: ".$mArray[clave2];
//E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant clave2 - assumed 'clave2' -- at line 23
//El valor es: valor:
?>
```

> En este caso PHP entiende que `clave2` es una contante ya que no esta delimitada entre comillas y además que no está definida, al no estar definida dicha constante, emite un E_NOTICE y asume que pretendiamos pasar un string por lo que termina interpretando `clave2` como string.

Segun el manual vemos en [Sintaxsis](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.syntax.php):

> Si se usa una constante que todavía no está definida, PHP asume que se está refiriendo al nombre de la constante en si, igual que si fuera una string (CONSTANT vs "CONSTANT"). Cuando esto suceda, se mostrará un error de nivel E_NOTICE.

---

Con la sintaxis compleja podemos pasar una constante como clave de un array, aun que no imprimir la constante de forma directa:

```
<?php
define('MI_CONSTANTE', "clave");
$mArray=array("clave"=>"valor array");
echo "El valor es: {$mArray[MI_CONSTANTE]}";
//  El valor es: valor array
echo "El valor es: {MI_CONSTANTE}";
// El valor es: {MI_CONSTANTE}
?>
```

> En el primer caso PHP al encontrar los simvolos `{$` el interprete entiende que debe interpretarlo como una variable. En el segundo caso no encuentra los simbolos `{$` solo `{` por lo que lo interpreta como un string literarlmente.

En sintaxis compleja podemos encontrar la siguiente nota:

> Dado que `{` no puede ser escapado, esta sintaxis será reconocida únicamente cuando el `$` siga inmediatamente al `{`.