# consulta por asignación de arreglos bidimensionales

Tags: php

Disculpen por lo básico de la pregunta, pero algo no debo estar haciendo bien, a pesar de que es muy simple.

Asigno un valor a un arreglo y lo despliega.  Lo hace perfecto.
`$arr1[0]=43;` y la sentencia `echo "$arr1[0]";` me muestra `43`

Pero asigno un valor a un arreglo bidimensional y no me resulta mostrarlo.
`$arr2[0][0]=43;` y la sentencia `echo "$arr2[0][0]";`  me muestra `Array[0]`

A lo mejor está almacenado correctamente, pero ¿cómo lo rescato?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿A qué se debe este funcionamiento en PHP cuando se usan valores de array dentro de comillas dobles y fuera de ellas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258326/a-qu%c3%a9-se-debe-este-funcionamiento-en-php-cuando-se-usan-valores-de-array-dentro)

Comment: Por si no ves la relación, el problema surge por el uso de las comillas a la hora de imprimir. La solución a tu problema es sacar las comillas e imprimir la variable directamente, es decir: `echo $arr2[0][0];`. Te recomiendo leer [este articulo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: Para no estar adivinando, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código con el que estás creando `$arr2`.

Answer (score 0):

Los arrays bidimensionales se generar con una fila y una columna (o clave y valor)

osea si tu quieres mostrar el resultado 43 seria algo como esto...

```
$array[0][0] = 42;
$array[0][1] = 43;
$array[0][2] = 43;
echo $array[0][1];
```

Primero indicamos el valor de la fila que queremos mostrar
Luego la columna que queremos mostrar, en este caso 43